# queryselectorAll() with regex attribute selector

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='pricing']"));
```

Returns an array with length 6.

```
var arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='tarification']"));
```

Also produces an array of length 6.

The context is a website with either English or French pages. Either of the two versions or arr will return 6 results on a given page while the other will produce an empty array.

I would like to dynamically account for this. So regardless if the user is on a French or English page I know that one or the other versions will return 6 elements. I could write an `if()` statement. But is there a neater, shorter way? I tried the following:

```
var arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='(tarification|pricing)']"));
```

But that also returned an empty array.

Comment: `a[href*='tarification'],a[href*='pricing']`

Comment: You want to know *which* one has 6 elements or *how many* elements has one of them (regardless which)?

Comment: @Al.G. I want to return an array of elements either based "tarification" or "pricing" in a oner. Looks like the first comment above might be what I'm after, will give it  a try...

Comment: I was just about to post an answer but thought about the other situation. Try it...

Comment: Anyway, I think you should to recognize(or even know, if it yours) localization and then search by relevant queries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's about css selectors, not regular expressions:

```
var arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='tarification'], a[href*='pricing']"));
```

The following selects all links with *pricing* or *tarification* in their `href`:

```
a[href*='tarification'], a[href*='pricing']
```