# Adding OR clause to document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing the same scenario as described [here in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713983/queryselectorall-with-regex-attribute-selector?rq=1). The solution is also acceptable but becomes tedious in worst case scenario. For instance, I'm trying to apply the technique for the following conceptual scenario:

```
<input id="txtXMLS01" />
<input id="txtXMLS02" />
<input id="txtXMLS03" />
.
.
.
<input id="txtXMLS100" />

<input id="txtXMLM01" />
<input id="txtXMLM02" />
<input id="txtXMLM03" />
.
.
.
<input id="txtXMLM100" />

<input id="txtSVGS01" />
<input id="txtSVGS02" />
<input id="txtSVGS03" />
.
.
.
<input id="txtSVGS100" />

<input id="txtSVGM01" />
<input id="txtSVGM02" />
<input id="txtSVGM03" />
.
.
.
<input id="txtSVGM100" />
```

Is there any other technique similar to that of the following snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textBox=document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=txt(XML|SVG)[S|M|L](\d)*]")
</script>
```

Add[1]: I am aiming at extracting only nodes that has the following pattern `txtXMLS*` `txtXMLM*` `txtSVGS*` `txtSVGM*`. Why I'm specific because there are other textboxes in the same page that starts with `txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS querySelectorAll and a regular expression as selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656449/js-queryselectorall-and-a-regular-expression-as-selector)

Comment: @SLePort: Bro, I have linked one of the hyperlinks in the question that is similar to the one you are pointing to. What I'm trying to achieve is that, Instead of coding `[id^=txtXMLS] [id^=txtXMLM] [id^=txtSVGS] [id^=txtSVGM]`, is there a single line technique so that the amount of coding gets reduced?

Comment: @SLePort Is there any terminology or technique for that?

Comment: The solution in the link you provide don't use regex, the Possible duplicate link (as well as below answer) does.

Comment: @SLePort Thanks dude, sorry got little confused with CSS selector based regex and JS Regex. The answer given below by `gurvinder372` works after tweaking it for my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` with `regex`

```
var textBoxes = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll("input[id]" ) ).filter( s => !!s.id.match( /txt(XML|SVG)[S|M|L](\d)*/ );
```

**Explanation**

- `Array.from` will convert the output of `document.querySelectorAll("input[id]" )` to array
- `filter` will filter the resultant array from `array.from` based on the condition passed as regex
- `!!s.id.match( /txt(XML|SVG)[S|M|L](\d)*/` will convert the match results to the equivalent *boolean* value.

Comment: don't you mean `/.../.test(s.id)`? That would be more canonical.

Comment: Yes @PatrickRoberts That would work as well. I will point that out to OP once he confirms that this solution works for him. Given the fact that OP hasn't shared a working snippet, I am finding it difficult to create a demo.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks bro. It helped me. I tweaked the code as follows

`var textBoxes = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=txt]" ) ).filter( s => /(XML[S|M]|SVG[S|M])(\d*)/.test(s.id));`